# How do I use Adobe Flash Player with more privacy?

Tags: firefox, flash, privacy, flash-player

For the past few months I have become more concerned with online privacy. That is because I became more aware of how much data is collected on internet users and how easily that data is obtained. I have adopted many new tools for increasing my digital privacy. Things like:

- Making use of a VPN service.
- Paying more attention to which software I use.
- Trying to educate myself more on digital privacy.

I recently wanted to use Adobe Flash player in browser for running some flash based applications, but I remembered hearing about many vulnerabilities associated with the platform. After doing some research and trying to understand those vulnerabilities a little more I began to ask myself how much of a significant privacy issue is flash. I have browsed for FireFox addons and installed a flash block extension to try that out.

Therefore my question is how concerned do I need to be with running flash from a web privacy viewpoint? What can I do to improve my web privacy around flash player? Are there other solutions to prevent flash sharing data? Is this something I need to be concerned about at all in the first place?

**Thank you for any help.**

Comment: I banned Flash from the entire building over 2 years ago. [Silverlight & Quicktime for Windows too] I rarely see sites that still use it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your reply. I'm mainly interested in running flash based web games, I don't think I'd use it in any other case because like you mentioned, It isn't used often anymore.

Comment: Then idk, sorry - that type of gaming is not something I've ever generally allowed in the building. One single proprietary system, no means of adequately securing it == *avoid like the plague.*

Comment: @Tetsujin That's beginning to seem like the only solution from a privacy outlook right now.

Comment: If you must use it, run in a sandbox, i.e. VM, or use Flash from a dedicated gaming machine (or Linux Live USB device), with no personally identifiable info. It will still pick up your location from ISP and any info browser leaks. See https://browserleaks.com/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the reply. What about downloading the SWF files I'm trying to run and running them locally or through a VM? Do you think that would be a better option? Do you think there is a way I could cut it off from sharing any data that way?

Comment: Yeah, a virgin VM with zero real user data sounds like a reasonable idea. tbh, I'd still find a new hobby.

Comment: @GemstarWife, just play .SWF files? In most cases, you don't need Adobe Flash at all! Just use another media player, such as MPC-HC or IrfanView. Both are free. Windows Media Player can also be used, but security settings must be reduced.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for following up with me. I know that they're are video players that will play flash videos, but I'd be curious to see if those support interactive flash applications. I know that there is an adobe progam called flash projector that can run interactive content, but I don't know if it would be safer than running the file in a browser window. If I could prevent it from connecting to the internet and sharing data I think it may be a great option.